# Bash won't recognize file test operators

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi2, debian-based

I'm running Raspbian-Wheezy (based on Debian) 3.18 on a Raspberry Pi 2.  When I try to use file test operators in bash, I am getting command not found errors.
For example:

`>> -d ./bin`

yields

`bash: -d: command not found`

This happens in both the terminal and in shell scripts for all file test operators I have tried (-d, -e, -f, etc.).  From what I can find, it seems these commands should be built in to bash.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Those aren't operators to the shell. They are operators to `test`/`[`. (e.g. `test -d ./bin` or `[ -d ./bin ]`.

Answer (score 3):

The file test operators are only recognized in the context of the `test` command (`test` or `[`...`]` or `[[`...`]]`).  That goes for other operators like `-z` or `-n` and so on, along with most other tests that you might want to use in a conditional expression:

```
$ test -d bin
$
```

Note that there's no output; it just sets the last status variable `$?` to 0 if true and 1 if false.  You have to use `if` or something to make use of the value:

```
if test -d ./bin; then
   echo "./bin is a directory"
else
   echo "./bin is not a directory"
fi
```

Comment: Using `if test -d` instead of `if [[ -d` is necessary if you need to pass the file test operator dynamically via variable.